# Как посчитать колличество нулей в конце числовой переменной?

Tags: python

```
    num = 234500
    zero_count = str(num)[::-1]
    count = 0
    for i in (range(0, len(zero_count))):
        while zero_count[i] != '1':
            count = count + 1
    print(count)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно обойтись без строк. Проверяем сколько раз число делится на 10 без остатка:

```
def zero_count(n):
    c = 0
    while n > 0:
        n, d = divmod(n, 10)
        if d != 0:
            return c
        c += 1
    return 1


print(zero_count(0))
print(zero_count(1))
print(zero_count(10))
print(zero_count(100100))
```

> ```
> $ python zero_count.py
> 1
> 0
> 1
> 2
> ```

Если доводить вариант со строками до ума:

```
def zero_count(n):
    for i, d in enumerate(reversed(str(n))):
        if d != '0':
            return i
    return 1
```

Регулярное выражение для подсчёта нулей в конце строки:

```
import re


def zero_count(n):
    return len(re.search('0*$', str(n))[0])
```

**P.S.** Все варианты хороши для не слишком длинных чисел. Но если у вас действительно большое число и в нём много нулей, то есть способы лучше...

Comment: вот такой вариан есть еще: return len(s := str(num)) - len(s.rstrip('0'))

Answer (score 1):

Два варианта, чтобы уйти от бесконечного цикла. Коррекции пояснены в коде комментариями.

Вариант 1 (оптимальный из двух):

```
num = 100100
zero_count = str(num)[::-1]
count = 0
# Не нужен тут цикл for, а вместо i сам count и используем 
while zero_count[count] == '0':
    count = count + 1
print(count)
```

Вариант 2 (коррекция в изначальном цикле for):

```
num = 100100
zero_count = str(num)[::-1]
count = 0
for i in (range(0, len(zero_count))):
    # Здесь нужен не бесконечный while, а if, если уж for использован
    if zero_count[i] == '0':
        count = count + 1
    # А здесь прервать нужно, если условие не выполнено     
    else:
        break
print(count)
```

Comment: Хм... а если 245 (к примеру) будет подано то посчитает в ответ значение 3... Может через while все же?

Comment: я понял из задачи, что мы говорим о двоичном коде, так как на равенство 1 автор проверял.

Comment: Автор всех обманул неудачным примером. Поменяйте условия в коде. Это не изменит ваш ответ по существу.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо, поменял:-)